# Can't use vector drawables in Android Studio 4.1 as it does not show vector clip-arts to choose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I was working on my project in previous version of Android Studio (4.0.1) when update notification came for Android Studio 4.1. I updated, did everything needed. While changing background of one of my layout, it showed me an Out Of Memory Error. I ignored that and don't know details about that error. Now when I go for a new vector drawables, it shows me nothing, even after I search with accurate name of clip-arts. What should I do now?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4W3E.png)

Comment: You are the fourth person to encounter this problem. :)

Comment: Very unluckily! Is there any way to get out of this?

Comment: I did not found

Answer (score 0):

check this one is added your apps gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Comment: I've just checked your solution, but it does not solve my problem. :(